# How much revenue do seat-back displays generate?

Tags: airline-operations

Many airlines are toying with the idea of getting rid of seat-back displays, how much revenue did those seat-back displays bring in the form of in-flight advertisement? I would presume for a long haul flight the revenue might be more than what it is for a mid-range flight.

Comment: 5 hours is short-range?

Comment: OK - my bad - short flight < 3 hours.

Comment: I removed reference to "short-range" flight

Comment: I don't have the precise numbers but those displays take up power (==fuel) and weight and need to be serviced. I'm sure that there is some tipping point between profit from adds and running cost that they are very carefully analyzing.

Comment: and airline that bombards me with advertising using their displays will find that I quickly position a towel or something to block it out, and probably won't fly that airline again...

Comment: I personally have seen very little advertising on seat-back displays, so I would suspect it's not much.

Comment: @cpast After crossing the Pacific a few times, yeah, 5 hour flights start to feel much shorter. - haha - Unless, of course, you're in an uncomfortable seat. Then they can feel longer than the 15 hour flights.

Comment: Honestly, I'd be surprised if advertising revenues ever neared the operational cost of the IFE systems, especially since, as GdD mentioned, there's usually not all that much advertising on them. Personally, I've mostly just seen advertising on them during boarding/deplaning when their entertainment functions usually aren't enabled.

Comment: OP: can you point to some sources for your assertion that "many airlines are..."

Comment: @CGCampbell I'm pretty sure Delta is considering this and I think it has even already done so on some of its fleet, opting to deliver content to passengers on their own devices over wi-fi instead. Southwest follows that model exclusively, but I don't think they ever had IFE systems to start with. There are a couple of articles about this [here](http://www.fastcodesign.com/3034196/terminal-velocity/airlines-are-tossing-seat-back-screens-here-is-why-thats-a-great-design-mo) and [here](http://www.engadget.com/2014/08/05/future-of-ife/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](http://skift.com/2014/09/18/aviation-tech-giants-join-forces-to-increase-airline-seat-revenue/) from September 2014:

> Thales estimates total revenue from IFE at \$17.6m a year for
>   small/mid-sized carriers, up to \$397m a year for large carriers.

But that's for all services, not just advertising. The only specific mention I could find of advertising was [this 2012 quote](http://airfax.com/blog/index.php/2012/11/20/how-much-money-has-your-ife-made/) attributed to the CEO of [Thompson Aerospace](http://www.thompsonaerospace.com/):

> Somewhere in the middle of the second question about advertising on
>   the system he said: “… and we are generating somewhere between \$20,000
>   and \$30,000 per month per plane with the IFE.”

The revenue is apparently generated in a similar way to internet advertising:

> [...] every 2 weeks the airline and the advertising service bureau receives
>   a summary of the requests/viewings and the airline gets a check. At 1
>   to 5 cents per click, the tally adds up as daily flights, sometimes
>   short as an hour, record revenue and usage every passenger, every
>   flight, every day, and every month

However, there's no information in the article about which airlines actually use that specific service, and I have no idea if those numbers are typical or not, or even exaggerated.

If you need more information than that and you can afford USD 4,650 to find out, [this](http://www.marketsandmarkets.com/Market-Reports/in-flight-entertainment-communications-market-860.html) looks like a comprehensive report on the IFE industry.